# Procedimiento almacenado dentro de otro procedimiento almacenado sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

lo que quiero hacer es poder integrar en un procedimiento almacenado(1) otro procedimiento almacenado(2) que el 2 se ejecute dentro del 1, que el resultado del 2 se guarde en una tabla temporal y luego poder utilizar los datos de esa tabla temporal en el 1, como se hace?

Utilizo Sql server managment studio 17

SP 2:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tempDep', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tempDep;
IF  EXISTS (SELECT
    *
FROM sys.objects
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[afiliacion].[spPrueba]')
AND type IN (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [afiliacion].[spPrueba]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [afiliacion].[spPrueba]
@dep_Id INT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT
dep_Nombre
FROM dep_Departamento
WHERE dep_Id = @dep_Id
GO
```

Comment: nos muestras que llevas?

Comment: Pues hasta el momento tengo un procedimiento que me retorna datos, solo necesito saber como meter ese procedimiento en otro para que en el otro pueda utilizar esos datos y meterlos en una temporal y utilizarlos

Comment: Coloca el código del primer procedimiento, te dan negativos porque no estás colocando nada de lo que llevas y pareciera que solo quieres la respuesta completa, además colocaste mal las etiquetas ya que no estas usando mysql. Por otro lado, puedes ejecutar el segundo sp con exec https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-execute-with-stored-procedures

Comment: No pues solo quiero saber con un ejemplo cono se hace

Comment: Si solo necesitas un ejemplo busca en google. Lee [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edita la pregunta.

Comment: No lo he encontrado, mira ya puse el codigo arriba

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas alternativas para lo que dices pero como ejemplo espero que te sirva:

```
-- Creamos el procedimiento interno 
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc2
    AS
BEGIN
    IF object_id(N'tempdb.dbo.##FromProc2', N'U') is not null 
        DROP TABLE ##FromProc2
    SELECT TOP 10 *
        INTO ##FromProc2
        FROM Cust_Employee
END

GO
-- Creamos el procedimiento externo que llama al 1 y extrae los resultados
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc1
    AS
BEGIN
    EXEC Proc2
    SELECT * 
        FROM ##FromProc2
    IF object_id('tempdb..##FromProc2') is not null 
        DROP TABLE ##FromProc2
END

GO
-- Llamamos al procedimiento y obtenemos resultados
EXEC Proc1
```

Answer (score 0):

El procedimiento almacenado lo ejectuas con 'Exec' y haces un 'INSERT INTO' a la tabla temporal:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable
(
   Col INT
)
INSERT INTO #tmpTable
Exec SpGet 'Params'
```

Comment: Gracias si me funciono